# MySQL SELECT WHERE IN query issue

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have `works` table, with columns `id`, `employer_key`, `task_key`, etc. The `task_key` column contains task keys such as `122,142,` or just one key `124,` or more.

My problem is when I do the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM works WHERE 122 IN(task_key)";
```

The query works only if the 122 is the first number listed, but if I search for 142, the second number listed, I don't get any result. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should change your schema but to do what you want you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * 
FROM works 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('122',task_key) > 0
```